Nvidia GeForce 7025 graphics not loading in Ubuntu 24.04
I've installed Ubuntu 24.04 and I have the nvidia card - Geforce 7025/NVIDIA nforce630a. I have installed latest nvidia-550 drivers but when I do nvidia-smi it is showing as "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make %0D%0Asure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."

This question is similar to: Nvidia Geforce GT 710 Driver Installation. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
